# Using Samba for Deployment to AWS Linux Instances

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, deployment, samba, network-shares

I currently have a very well developed web build and deployment infrastructre with Jenkins to handle builds and kick off deployment profiles managed by ViceVersa via Windows files shares.  All my servers currently are Windows 2012 instances on AWS.  I am going to migrating many of my services to Linux/Django/Python architecture and would like to keep my infrastructure as is.  Would using Samba to mount Linux as windows shares be reliable or should I move to rsynch.

i can't use SVN update to do deployments since I need to be able to control which files get deployed by the jenkins Job.

One of the best features of ViceVersa is it has the functionality of  keeping a tracking database so the targets don't have to be compared each time. this is helpful for some of our sites that have many files.  Do any linux deployment tools have this?

Comment: so you have S3 storage in AWS, why still keep the old way and think of Samba? To upload and download from S3 is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cifs mount of the windows fileshare on the Linux instance.  You'd want to define them in fstab if you want the fileshare mounted between instance restarts.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently